# Unable to check in after adding database files to TFS databases

Tags: tfs

Slight difficulty with Team Foundation Server 2008 databases (using Sql Server 2005).

Team System reported running out of disk space so I added another data file to each and every Team System database (on another fixed drive) to increase the disk space available. I did it as follows for each TFS database:

1. Add another file, type=Data, size etc = defaults, path to new drive.
2. Change the original data file to stop further expansion (Autogrowth=none).
3. Restart Sql Server.

That is the documented method for adding further space to a Sql Server 2005 database. However now I find I can check out files, but not check in. In Visual Studio, Source Control Explorer displays projects and can be expanded to show folders and files as normal, but When I rt-click on a checked-out file and select 'check in', nothing happens and the file remains checked out, and then Visual Studio has to be terminated using Task Manager.

There don't seem to be any related errors in the server Event Log.

What have I missed or done wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to clean the TFS cache on your client?

Comment: TFS 2008 has not been supported for quite a while! Using unsupported software puts your organisational asset (your code) at risk. You should upgrade or move to VSTS...

Comment: Is that a supported configuration for TFS 2008? Not all SQL features are supported...

Comment: @Neil Haughton, do you use the Database Mirroring feature?

Comment: "Using unsupported software ...." Not sure what that has to do with it. Software doesn't wear out and Sql Server 2005 works well enough still (this is a legacy archive system, by the way.).

Comment: "clean the TFS cache" Yes I have, but how would that help? TFS and Team Explorer surely don't care how or where Sql Server stores the actual data?

Comment: "clean the TFS cache" actually solved the problem. I think there may have been two problems, because I can't for the life of me see how the client end cache could know about how or where Sql Server stores the data (nor should it), but I tihknk that by coincidence the cahe was causing a problem with checking in that I only noticed after adding the extra database files. Thanks for the suggestion, TfsAgent!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"clean the TFS cache", posted by TfsAgent, actually solved the problem. Nothing to do with adding extra database files after all - that was a coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the 'Database Mirroring' feature to add a database file for a mirrored database that has different drives and/or paths.

Firstly, check this MSDN article for the detailed steps on how to "Configure SQL Server Mirroring for the TFS Data-Tier Server": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa980629(v=vs.90).aspx

Secondly, follow steps in this article about how to "Fail Over to a Mirrored Data-Tier Server if the Principal Server is Unavailable": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa980528(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but how does Mirroring solve the current problem? I simply want to increase the storage space for the existing databases, because their current drive has run out of space. The documented way to do that is to add additonal files, and that is what is not working, and what I need advice on.